# Dependency of auto-complete

Tags: package-repositories

I asked this questions on [Github](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/623#issuecomment-138132983)
I have just switched form auto-complete mode to company mode, but the error message

> Warning (emacs): Unable to activate package jedi'. Required packageauto-complete->1.4' is unavailable

pops out. Do I have to install "auto-complete" (even I don't use it) to activate jedi?

Answer (score 2):

You need to uninstall [jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) and install [company-jedi](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi).

Comment: Thanks, but in this case ,may I still use jedi as the library, or the package "jedi-core" and "company-jedi" is enough? Do I have to uninstall jedi from pip?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that. If you find documentation for these projects insufficient, you can file an issue about that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Jedi. Use **anaconda-mode**. Jedi not work with company-mode and work with errors in company-jedi (or I can't configure it).

Comment: Thanks for ur advices. Updated info with [author of company-jedi](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi/issues/8#issuecomment-139103736).